# Vite config on docker

Tags: laravel, docker, vite

I'm using a machine on my network (not the one I use to edit/view the application) to host a docker laravel application.

I'm struggling setting up vite.

I get the console errors:

jobs:20

```
   GET http://[::]:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

jobs:20

```
   GET http://[::]:5173/resouces/css/app.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

jobs:20

```
   GET http://[::]:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

jobs:500

```
   GET http://[::]:5173/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

My vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: true,
    },
    hmr: {
        base: '192.168.1.216',
        port: '94',
    },
  plugins: [
    
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
      refresh: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

The laravel app is working fine on http://192.168.1.216:94/

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  freelancerapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.1.0-fpm
    container_name: freelancerapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: freelancerapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - freelancerapp-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserverfreelancer:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserverfreelancer
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "94:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - freelancerapp-network

  #MySQL Service
  freelancerdb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: freelancerdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    networks:
      - freelancerapp-network
#Docker Networks
networks:
  freelancerapp-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  freelancerdbdata:
    driver: local
```

I'm using npm run dev to run the vite server. I'm presuming my vite set up is wrong as I've not used vite before. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Laravel, Vite, Docker.

Comment: Your Docker Compose configuration doesn't expose port 5173, which probably is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
server: {
    strictPort: true,
    port: 5173,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
    },
    watch: {
        ignored: ['./app/**', './bootstrap/**', './config/**', './database/**', './lang/**', './node_modules/**', './public/**', './routes/**', './storage/**', './tests/**', './vendor/**'],
    },
}
```

You need to use a configuration like this if using an older version and build. for some reason it doesn't know what to target unless its set as such. nowadays with the newer version it is not needed. hope it helps!

* PS: Some of the rules are not needed and can be dropped, this is just what I needed and worked in my exact case.